# Change the Brightness of a div when hovering over another div

Tags: javascript, html, css

There is div #hovertrigger1 and div #gallery1. They cant be parents, children, or children of the same parent. I want #gallery1 to darken, when the mouse hovers over #hovertrigger1.
I guess it has to be written in Javascript and cant be solved in CSS. This is what the HTML looks like:

```
<div>
</div>
<div class="container">

    <div class="hovertrigger" id="hovertrigger1"></div>
    <div class="logoanim" id="logoanim1"><img src="" alt="" class="wp-image-536"></div>
    <div class="logo" id="logo1"><img src="" alt="" class="wp-image-587"></div>
  
    
</div>

<div class="wp-block-gmedia-gallery gmedia-shortcode" id="gallery1">[gmedia id=13]</div>
```

Comment: Can you post whatever CSS you have already?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the css `filter` property and apply a brightness filter through JavaScript.

```
document.getElementById('hovertrigger1').addEventListener('mouseover', () => {
    document.getElementById('gallery1').style.filter = 'brightness(0.5)';
});
```

Comment: Get the element references before the event handler fires otherwise you’ll be scanning the Dom over and over again for the same elements.

Answer (score 0):

Use JS to add a hover function.

```js
let HoverTrigger = document.getElementById("hovertrigger1") // hovertrigger1
let Gallery1 = document.getElementById("gallery1") // gallery1
let BrightnessLevel = 0 // 0 to 1 (0 being dark, 1 being light)

HoverTrigger.onmouseover(() => {
    Gallery1.style.filter = `brightness(${BrightnessLevel})`
})
```

If you want it to stop when you hover off, you can add another function:

```js
HoverTrigger.onmouseout(() => {
    Gallery1.style.filter = "brightness(1)"
})
```

Comment: The second event is called onmouseout and not onmouseoff

Comment: You can use const instead of let.